# Finding the surface area of a "slanted" solid

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

[image]

How can I find the surface area of this solid? I know that the area of the front and back is $8·10$, and that the area of the top and bottom is $8·6$, but I'm not sure how to find the area of the right and left sides. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $s$ is the length of the side of the front face, then you know that

$$ \frac{10}{s}=\sin60^\circ$$

You already know the base of the right and left faces is $6$. So with that and the value of $s$ you can find the area.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: the right and left sides are rectangles. You just have to find the side lengths.